# C# .net 4.0 Upload a file to .asp Web API

Tags: c#, rest, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

My .net 4.0 class library send HttpRequestMessage and receive HttpResponseMessage from .asp Web API (REST).

When I sent a small class, I use JSON to parse it as string, then I send string by:

```
request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri(myRestAPI);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
request.Method = method;
if (method != HttpMethod.Get)
   request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, mthv);
```

Next, use HttpClient to send it:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = _client.SendAsync(request).Result)
{..}
```

This works **fine**.
Now, my class has got bigger, How can i send it ?
What i did was to zip it and send as ByteArrayContent.

```
request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
request.Method = method;
if (method != HttpMethod.Get)
   request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(content);
   request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
```

And send it the same way.

But now the server does reply me with error:

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Byte[]' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.
```

What am I doing wrong ?? I am trying to find a proper guide and all the guides are talking about uploading **FROM** web api and not about uploading from **application to** web api..

Comment: ByteArrayContent sends the media type `application/octet-stream`.  If you really wanted to send multipart form data then you would use the MultiPartFormDataContent class.  Either way, you shouldn't be changing the content-type just because you want to compress.  That's why there is a separate content-encoding header.

Answer (score 3):

Go get WebAPIContrib, it has a [CompressedContent](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Content/CompressedContent.cs) class

With it you can do,

```
request.Content = new CompressedContent(new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, mthv),"gzip");
```

and compression will just magically just happen.

Comment: Hi, is this valid for .net 4.0 ? When i receive it on my Controller, Do I do the same as before ? - before i just had the object as input parameter in (..[FromBody] mySerializedClass..)

Comment: @ilansch That class works fine in .net 4. As far as decompressing on the server.  I think IIS will do it automatically, however, if you are on self host you might need a MessageHandler.

Comment: @ilansch  The GZipStream class can decompress as well as compress.  There is an example of how to do it here https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/MessageHandlers/EncodingHandler.cs

Comment: I was trying what you said, i receive null in my controller:   [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStatus([FromBody]MyClass systemBase, [FromUri]string systemId, [FromUri]string af = "")
  {